# Issue casting function to generic function pointer implementing Trait

Tags: rust, traits

I have a problem casting a function into a function pointer, returning a generic type implementing Future.

Let me explain:

I have a trait

```rust
trait Foo {
   type Future: Future<Output = Result<(), Error>>;
   fn bar(&self) -> Self::Future;
}
```

Which is implemented for any `fn()` that returns a Future with the corresponding output.

```rust
impl<Fut: Future<Output = Result<(), Error>>> Foo for fn() -> Fut {
   type Future = Fut;
   fn bar(&self) -> Self::Future {
      self()
   }
}
```

I assumed that you could call `bar()` on any `fn()` that returned a Future with the corresponding output if you cast it to a type matching the one Foo is implemented for.

```
async fn test() -> Result<(), Error> {
    /* ... */
}

Foo::bar(&test as _)
```

rustc is telling me:

```bash
rustc: the trait `Foo` is implemented for fn pointer `fn() -> Fut`, try casting using `as`: ` as fn() -> Fut`
```

But I don't know how to cast to a type containing generics.

I think this is related to this [issue about inferrence failure on general `Fn*` traits](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/99991).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of the issue here is precedence `&test as _` converts the reference to a function pointer, but you need a reference to a function pointer, not a plain function pointer so you have to write `&(test as _)` instead, but that doesn't satisfy the compiler either (it doesn't know if you want to cast to `fn`, `Fn`, `FnMut` or `FnOnce`, some other trait, ...?), you can further restrict the type you cast to by just providing enough information so the compiler can figure out the rest:

```rust
Foo::bar(&(test as fn() -> _));
```

You can further simplify this by using method syntax instead, that way the compiler can figure out all the reference business:

```rust
(test as fn() -> _).bar();
```

The whole problem arises because without any casting each function is a different `fn` *item* which can often avoid any allocation at all when working with them but you have to convert it to a function pointer first.

While this might work the proper solution would be to take `self` by value instead of by reference, that doesn't change anything for function pointers and enables you to implement `Foo` for `FnOnce` instead:

```rust
use std::future::Future;
trait Foo {
   type Future: Future<Output = Result<(), ()>>;
   fn bar(self) -> Self::Future;
}

impl<F: FnOnce() -> Fut, Fut: Future<Output = Result<(), ()>>> Foo for F {
   type Future = Fut;
   fn bar(self) -> Self::Future {
      self()
   }
}

async fn test() -> Result<(), ()> {
    Ok(())
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    _ = test.bar().await;
}
```

Notice how with the change from `&self` to `self` and `fn() -> Fut` to `F: FnOnce() -> Fut` we now no longer need to cast the function to anything at all.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a655f81857ac3956f5c25b4da80da88f)

Comment: Don't know what you mean you can't cast a function item taking a parameter to a function pointer taking no parameters or vice versa. For anything taking the same amount of parameters `(test as fn(_, _) -> _)` where you put as many `_` as you have parameters should work.

Comment: Okay, try this playground example https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=411e7898cddf169556ee91735133c918. I think the problem is that the Future gets tied to the lifetime of the past reference, which makes it a non-primitive cast.

Comment: That's a different question from the original post, feel free to ask another question. If you do, you can and probably should link to this one.

Comment: Thank you for the help on this one, I have opened a new questing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75947795/trait-binding-lifetimes-of-futures-to-fn-arguments. I will close this one with your answer.