# Trait binding lifetimes of Futures to fn arguments

Tags: rust, traits

Let's assume there is a trait `Foo`:

```rust
trait Foo {
   type Future: Future<Output = ()>;
   fn bar(&self, a: &str) -> Self::Future;
}
```

Which has a required method `bar` that takes a reference to self as well as a reference to a string slice and returns a Future.

Let's implement `Foo` for any `fn` that takes a reference to a string slice and returns the appropriate future.

```rust
impl<Fut: Future<Output = ()>> Foo for fn(&str) -> Fut {
   type Future = Fut;
   fn bar(&self, a: &str) -> Self::Future {
      self(a)
   }
}
```

Now, let's try to call `bar` on an `async fn` that takes a reference to a string slice.

```rust
async fn test(a: &str) {
    /* ... */
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    Foo::bar(&(test as fn(&str) -> _), "Hello world");
}
```

Although `test` has the correct function signature, and it returns the right future, the type cast from `test_function` to `fn(&str) -> _` fails.

```rust
error[E0605]: non-primitive cast: `for<'a> fn(&'a str) -> impl Future<Output = ()> {test}` as `for<'a> fn(&'a str) -> _`
  --> src/main.rs:21:15
   |
21 |     Foo::bar(&(test as fn(&str) -> _), "Hello world");
   |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ invalid cast
```

[Try it yourself](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3142c0507b4be7a367645d78335e6102)

From my understanding, this is reason do to the binding of the `impl Futere`, that is returned from `test`, to the parameter lifetime `a`.

The only, non-nightly solution, I could think of was to introduce a lifetime in the trait.

```rust
trait Foo<'a> {
   type Future: Future<Output = ()> + 'a;
   fn bar(&self, a: &'a str) -> Self::Future;
}

impl<'a, Fut: Future<Output = ()> + 'a> Foo<'a> for fn(&'a str) -> Fut {
   type Future = Fut;
   fn bar(&self, a: &str) -> Self::Future {
      self(a)
   }
}
```

With some very experimental features in nightly, I came up with this:

```rust
#![feature(return_position_impl_trait_in_trait)]
use std::future::Future;

trait Foo {
   fn bar<'a>(&self, a: &'a str) -> impl Future<Output = ()> + 'a;
}

impl<Fut> Foo for fn(&str) -> Fut
where 
    for<'a> Fut: Future<Output = ()> + 'a,
{
   fn bar(&self, a: &str) -> Fut {
      self(a)
   }
}

async fn test(a: &str) {
    /* ... */
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    Foo::bar(&(test as fn(&str) -> _), "Hello world");
}
```

[Try it yourself](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=badd5837d208b4ab39d10504ac8276ef)

But this still results in the same non-primitive type cast error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever I run into weird lifetime issues like this my first instinct is always to explicitly write out the lifetimes and see where we mess up.

Let's go and write out the lifetimes we expect:

```rust
trait Foo<'s> {
   type Future: Future<Output = ()>;
   fn bar<'t>(&'t self, a: &'s str) -> Self::Future;
}

impl<'s, Fut: Future<Output = ()>> Foo<'s> for fn(&'s str) -> Fut {
   type Future = Fut;
   fn bar<'t>(&'t self, a: &'s str) -> Self::Future {
      self(a)
   }
}
```

Now our code *just works* if we change `as fn(&str) -> _` to `as fn(_) -> _`:

```rust
async fn test(a: &str) {
    /* ... */
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    Foo::bar(&(test as fn(_) -> _), "Hello world");
}
```

Wait, what? This is really weird, right? How come we just explicitly wrote out the lifetimes and now our program just works? Why do we need the `as fn(_) -> _`? Why can't we use `as fn(&str) -> _`? To be honest I have no clue. Regardless of cause, hopefully this answer helps you.